# Configure VM network settings to ssh into a mininet VM

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am trying to configure my VM (mininet vmdk) network settings in order to ssh into it from my host machine. I am using virtualbox as my hypervisor.

Per the Mininet instructions (http://mininet.org/vm-setup-notes/), I added an additional host-only adapter on my VM. On my network settings, I have Adapter 1 configured to be NAT, and Adapter 2 configured to a host-only adapter. However, when I use ifconfig in the virtual machine, there is only eth0 and lo listed. eth0 does not have an IP address associated with it; could someone explain why this is the case? Shouldn't there be another eth1 interface listed (for the host-only adapter)?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is eth0 for adapter 1 or 2? Compare the MAC address from ifconfig with the MAC addresses in the Virtualbox networks tab. Also, do you have a DHCP server configured on your host-only network?

Answer (score 0):

To which adapter is eth0 tied NAT or Host-Only? You can confirm using the mac-address. Also you can check if the VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter is created/present on your windows machine where you are running your virtual box.

```
Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 08-00-27-00-E4-FD
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b9c4:1994:c678:3e0f%24(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 772276263
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-18-87-69-22-F0-DE-F1-34-AB-6C
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

If this adapter is not created or configured properly eth1 won't show up in the mininet vm.